# java android programing.. obtain ip address from user

Tags: java, android

i wrote android code to obtain an IP address from user in EditText, then communicate the mobile with a computer ip which obtained  by user in EditText.

this is my code, when I click on button nothing work:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button b;
EditText et;
TextView tv;
private Socket socket;
int PORT = 4003;
String HOST; //HOST = " 192.168.2.1"

private Handler textview_handler_thread;
class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
            Message msg = null;
            while(true) {      
                msg = textview_handler_thread.obtainMessage();
                msg.obj = "Process Completed Succesfully";
                textview_handler_thread.sendMessage(msg);
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    HOST = et.getText().toString();

    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();

    textview_handler_thread = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Object o = msg.obj;

            if (o == null) 
                o = "";

            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv.setText(o.toString());
        }
        };

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            try {
                DataOutputStream output_to_server = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                String client_str = et.getText().toString();
                    output_to_server.writeBytes(client_str);
                    output_to_server.flush();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}
```

The problem in HOST variable it shoul contain IP address from user.
At first i wrote HOST = "192.168.2.1";
But now i want the user do that.

NOTE : if i wrote HOST = "192.168.2.1"; it is executed successfully. when I assigned the valu of HOST to edit Text CANT communicate with the computer WHY?

Comment: It doesn't seem you start the Handler

Comment: Are you getting the user input value in `HOST` ?

Comment: Remove getText() from onCreate() and put in onClick()

Comment: yes jgm the user input should saved in HOST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you assign the value to HOST at OnCreate. At that time, that text box is still empty yet.

You may want to do it in the OnClick event

```
String client_str = et.getText().toString();
HOST = Client_str;
```

At this time, HOST shall contain the IP address the user typed. Also, you shall not start the thread at OnCreate. At that time, HOST has nothing yet.

Comment: thank you... please can you edit my code. your comment not clear to me.

Comment: how can i send a textview content to the c# application please??

Comment: Could you be more specific? Sometime just pass a string would be enough